# Quais as diferenças entre setInterval x requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, desempenho

Estou criando uma aplicação onde eu preciso verificar se um elemento X foi criado na página e assim, tomar algumas ações. Para fazer essa verificação, estou utilizando o `setInterval`.

Alguns minutos atrás, eu me lembrei que existe a função `requestAnimationFrame`, utilizada geralmente para criar jogos. Também lembrei que essa função é muito mais rápida, ou melhor dizendo, mais "fluída" **aparentemente** do que o `setInterval`.

Então eu fiquei pensando. Qual dessas duas funções é a melhor? Quais as desvantagens e vantagens de cada uma delas?

Por que não passamos a usar somente `requestAnimationFrame` quando não precisamos definir um tempo de espera já que ela possui **aparentemente** um desempenho melhor? Além disso, se essa função for realmente melhor, por que não criar uma parâmetro para passar um tempo de espera e assim substituir a função `setInterval`?

Agora voltando para a pergunta principal: qual a diferença entre a função `requestAnimationFrame` e a função `setInterval` de uma forma bem aprofundada?

Comment: Outra diferença fundamental é que `requestAnimationFrame` não executa o callback se a aba ativa do navegador não for a da aplicação ou o navegador for minimizado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `requestAnimationFrame()` e a função `setInterval()` fazem coisas completamente diferentes.

A função `setInterval()` configura um *timer* (cronômetro) e executa uma função ou um trecho de código quando esse *timer* expira. Utilizando `setInterval()`, o desenvolvedor pode mandar o browser executar uma ação a cada X milissegundos.

Já o `requestAnimationFrame()` fala para o navegador que deseja-se realizar uma animação e pede que o navegador chame uma função específica para atualizar um quadro de animação antes da próxima *repaint* (repintura).

Note que em `requestAnimationFrame()` o desenvolvedor não pode configurar um intervalo de tempo, pois o momento quando ocorrerá o próximo redesenho da tela depende do browser. É uma forma do desenvolvedor dizer "browser, quando você for redesenhar a tela, execute essas ações, desenhe isso também".

Ao se construir jogos, é comum utilizar as duas funções para realizar tarefas distintas. Por exemplo, o desenvolvedor pode criar uma função para desenhar algo na tela e utilizar `requestAnimationFrame()` para chamar essa função no momento correto. Assim, o desenho será feito no momento ideal, de forma eficiente.

Por outro lado, o desenvolvedor pode atualizar as informações do jogo em *background*, utilizando o `setInterval()` ou o `setTimeout()`, independente do que estiver sendo exibido na tela. Assim, quando for a hora de desenhar na tela, as informação já estarão pré-processadas.

Referências:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Games/Anatomy